# Conditional Navigation of rich:dataTable using rich:dataScroller

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

When the user tries to switch on to the next page of the rich:dataTable using rich:dataScroller, basing on a JS condition, an Alert will be displayed. If OK'd then only the 2nd page has to be shown. If Cancel'd then the first page itself should be displayed.

In richfaces3.3, there was onPageChange event on dataScroller, which is not available in richfaces 4.3. Pls suggest.

Comment: Did you try `scrollListener`?

Comment: You should be able to replace the `onPageChange` from 3.3 with the new er `onBegin` for 4.x